# Why does this code show output 17 and not 16?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

Please step by step explanation if possible

```
package array;

public class array3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            if (i == 3) { 
                result += 10;
            } else {
                result += i;
            }   
        }
        System.out.print(result);       
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you really need to turn to stack overflow; so that somebody suggests to you to put print statements also in your IF blocks to figure what is going?

Comment: Instead of asking US to show YOU step by step why the output is 17 and not 16, you should us why you excpect 16 (step by step ;))

Comment: If you use an IDE you should also check the debug mode and the use of breakpoints..

Comment: @Loci I am new at all this,i didn't know i could use sdebug mode for step by step

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i` loops from 0 to 4

```
+--------+-------------+
|   i    |   result    |
+--------+-------------+
|   0    |    0        |
|   1    | 0 + 1  = 1  |
|   2    | 1 + 2  = 3  |
|   3    | 3 + 10 = 13 |
|   4    | 13 + 4 = 17 |
+--------+-------------+
```

That's how you get 17

Comment: @DaX Then how did you arrive at 16? I guess you went both branches of your if for i==3.

Answer (score 0):

Your code increments(adds) the value of the 'i' index variable(type integer) of your current iterration to/in the 'result' variable(also, type integer). Only if i==3, then result = result+10, else result = result+i. Hope this clarifies.